# Robotframework- increment text box value

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to get the value from a text box on an html page.
Increase this value . Clear the existing value from the textbox and insert the incremented value.

Eg. The text box for add to cart. Has the value 2 for chocolates. I want to clear this value and enter the new value of 2+ 1 = 3
I am using robot framework and python .

I tried clear element keyword but this seems to be adding the 3 after the inserted value    ie.
2 initial value
3 updated value
The textbox reads 23 instead of 3

Your help will be greatly  affected.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would help if you can write out the code to show what you tried. You can format code blocks using three backticks (`) or tildes (~) on the lines before and after your code. More formatting help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

The `Input Text`Command should clear the Textfield from alone.

`Clear Element Text` is the only other Keyword I know to modify textfields.

Comment: I do not quite understand your answer.  `Input Text` could modify a text field as well. You mean `Input Text` won't clear it, only `Clear Element Text` will do that?

Comment: `Input Text ` should clear the Text. If there is a Problem with this use `Clear Element Text`, and a sleep function bevore using `Input Text`.